# Method doesn't refresh data after DismissViewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am developing iPhone app, where i got stuck at one point.

The error i am facing is, i have one tableview in `FirstViewController` on click of cell i am presenting `SecondViewController` on `SecondViewController` i have one button, on click of that button i am dismissing my presentViewController and again comes back to `FirstViewController` on `FirstViewController` i am calling one method that method gets called successfully but it doesn't perform inner task of that method, (means i want to reload my tableview it doesn't reloads my tableview, i want to change title text of that page but it doesn't change)

Here is my code snippet:

`FirstViewController:`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    SecondViewController *Obj= [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:Obj animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

`Code on SecondViewController:`

```
- (IBAction)ButtonClick:(id)sender {

    FirstViewController *Obj=[[FirstViewController alloc] init];

    [Obj MethodCall];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

`after dismissing SecondViewController, code on FirstViewController`

```
-(void) MethodCall
 {
    NSLog(@" -- MethodCall Success --");
    self.title=@"From back";
    [tblView reloadData];
 }
```

My log shows -- MethodCall Success -- but it neither Reloads my tableview nor changes the title of FirstViewController.

Where i am doing mistake ?

**Please help and thanks for reading.**

**NEW EDIT:**

`code on FirstViewController:`

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(tableReload) name:@"tableReload" object:nil];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:@"tableReload" object:nil];
}

-(void)tableReload{
    NSLog(@"-- FromSeeMore PushAndShowMerchants -- = %@",FromSeeMore);

    [tblList reloadData];

}
```

`code on SecondViewController :`

```
- (IBAction)SeemoreClick:(id)sender {  

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"tableReload" object:nil];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: Is CouponListViewController = FirstViewController? I think you can not call a method in order to update the FirstViewController. You need to use delegate or NSNotification to update the FirstViewController.

Comment: sorry, please see my new EDIT..

Comment: Check my answer. I just show you example on user NSNotification. But if you know how to use Delegate, it would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should follow object creation and methods declaration in Objective-C

`SecondViewController *Obj` it should be as `SecondViewController * obj`

`-(void) MethodCall` it should be as `-(void) methodCall`

`- (IBAction)ButtonClick:(id)sender` is should be `- (IBAction)ButtonClick:(id)sender`

And, Where did you call your method `MethodCall` in `FirstViewController`?

Did you try to use Delegate option to send the data to previous view controller?

Example :

In your `FirstViewController.h`

```
@protocol FirstControllerDelegate

-(void)dataUpdated:(NSArray *)array;

@end

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <FirstControllerDelegate>

@end
```

In your `FirstViewController.m`

```
-(void)dataUpdated:(NSArray *)array
{
    NSLog(@" -- MethodCall Success -- :%@", array);

    self.title=@"From back";

    [tblView reloadData];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    SecondViewController *Obj= [[SecondViewController alloc] init];

    Obj.delegate = self;

    [self.navigationController presentViewController:Obj animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

In `SecondViewController.h`

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <FirstControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

In `SecondViewController.m`

```
- (IBAction)ButtonClick:(id)sender 
{
    FirstViewController *Obj=[[FirstViewController alloc] init];

    [_delegate dataUpdated:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Object Passed"]];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: sorry, please see my new EDIT

Comment: I am not getting properly dude, what should i write in FirstViewController.h ?

Comment: What kind of data do you need to pass in delegate method? If you want to pass an array. Please see above edited code.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:-

In **FirstViewController**

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
 [super viewWillAppear:animated];
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(tableReload) name:@"tableReload" object:nil];
 }

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
 [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:@"tableReload" object:nil];
}

-(void)tableReload{
self.tableView.delegate=self;
self.tableView.dataSource=self;
[self.tableView reloadData];
self.title=@"From back";
}
```

On **SecondViewController**:

```
- (IBAction)ButtonClick:(id)sender {
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"tableReload" object:nil];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: `-(void)tableReload` not getting called

Comment: Are you sure you have this [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"tableReload" object:nil];
 on SecondViewController?

Comment: this method is not getting called from `viewWillAppear ` and from `SecondViewController` both

Comment: The is NSNotification, it will only call when you use postNotificationName. On the SecondViewController, when ButtonClick is pressed, then only the method will be called.

Comment: Yes dude not getting called.. :(

Comment: See my **NEW EDIT** in the question

Comment: From the New Edit. The tableReload method should be notified. I have no idea why it is not called. If you are able to update a more complete sample code to Github, then I only be able to help you more.. if not, it is really tough.

Comment: If you have read all this and nothing works, see my answer in this question, you just have to wait the animation to complete.

Answer (score 0):

@Natarajan - It's just a convention. Like all conventions they only serve to make code easier to read and maintain, for others people who will work with your code,Also .NET adopted ToString() as a convention. So it doesn't really matters how you name your methods...A lot of conventions say you capitalise the first letter of types (classes, structs, enums, etc.), and use lowercase otherwise (functions, members, etc.).But this wasn't the question asked .

The question for @Krunal will be where do you call `MethodCall`, and are you sure you change data in your table before you reload them? you can check using breakpoints if the table is reloaded if you say that NSLog is called that means the `[tblView reloadData];` is called but it has nothing to reload

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same idea as @Ricky and I have the same problem from a Modal window the notification where never called (so I searched the web for a solution) so you have to wait for the animation to complete so I have reach a solution and I'm going to add the solution to his code.

As he mentioned you have to add the observer in the viewDidAppear and remove it in the viewWillDisappear and in your second viewcontroller you have to add this code:

```
- (IBAction)ButtonClick:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^(void){
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"tableReload" object:nil];
    }];
}
```

Doing this, it will call viewDidAppear in the first viewcontroller and then postNotificationName so the method tableReload will get called.

Regards and happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use `NSNotificationCenter` for your problem.

Define a `NSNotification` in your MasterViewController viewDidLoad like below

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(closeModal:) name:@"CloseModal" object:nil];
```

And then define the method as below

```
(void)closeModal:(NSNotification *)notification{
    UIViewController *controller=(UIViewController *)notification.object;

    [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^ {
         [self getPostData];                 // Reload Data
         [self.tableView reloadData];        // Reload Data
    }];

}
```

And at last from your other controller from where you are actually trying to dismiss your controller use code below